# How to ressolve the error: Not creating XLA devices- tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision

It is a traffic sign recognition project where I have already run the training code and got the training accuracy. Then when I run testing code it gives me an error. The laptop's camera gets turned on but I don't get any interface to test my inputs.

***The code is:***

```
import img as img
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import pickle
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

#############################################
frameWidth = 640  # CAMERA RESOLUTION
frameHeight = 480
brightness = 180
threshold = 0.75  # PROBABLITY THRESHOLD
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
##############################################
# SETUP THE VIDEO CAMERA
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)
#####IMPORT THE TRAINED MODEL#####
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'


def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img


def equalize(img):
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    return img


def preprocessing(img):
    img = grayscale(img)
    img = equalize(img)
    img = img / 255
    return img


def getCalssName(classNo):
    if classNo == 0:
        return 'Speed Limit 20 km/h'
    elif classNo == 1:
        return 'Speed Limit 30 km/h'
     .......
     .......
    elif classNo == 40:
        return 'Roundabout mandatory'
    elif classNo == 41:
        return 'End of no passing'
    elif classNo == 42:
        return 'End of no passing by vechiles over 3.5 metric tons'


while True:
    # READ IMAGE
    success, imgOrignal = cap.read()
# PROCESS IMAGE
img = np.asarray(imgOrignal)
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
img = preprocessing(img)
cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "CLASS: ", (20, 35), font,
            0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "PROBABILITY: ", (20, 75),
            font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
# PREDICT IMAGE
predictions = model.predict(img)
classIndex = model.predict_classes(img)
probabilityValue = np.amax(predictions)
if probabilityValue > threshold:
    # print(getCalssName(classIndex))
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(classIndex) + " " + str(getCalssName(classIndex)),
                (120, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(round(probabilityValue * 100, 2)) + "%",
                (180, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow("Result", imgOrignal)

if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
    "break"
cv2.waitkey(0) == ord(q)
```

The error is

> 2021-08-29 18:34:31.841473: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll
> not found
> 2021-08-29 18:34:31.843330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart
> dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.621957: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA
> devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.626059: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could
> not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.626801: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to
> cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.634015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving
> CUDA diagnostic information for host: CHOWDHURY-JOY-LPTP
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.634852: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname:
> CHOWDHURY-JOY-LPTP
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.641932: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX2
> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2021-08-29 18:34:46.644266: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA
> devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
As a heads up: you probably won't get many responses to your question, as your code is much longer than the average person on here is willed to read through. To increase your chances of getting a response, I'd suggest your provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

These warnings occurred as `CuDNN.dll` is not found (which is used for running on GPU)

You can surpass these warnings using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46479#issuecomment-762161334) similar resolved issue for more details.